# Non-cartesian coordinate integration in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, chemistry

I have a function defined in elliptic coordinates. How can I symbolically integrate it in SymPy? Otherwise, do you have an example of implementation of any other non-Cartesian integration?

```
    import sympy as sym

    r = sym.Symbol('r')
    Z = sym.Symbol('Z', constant = True) 

    #1s normalized orbital definition
    def f(r):
        return (1/(sym.pi)) * (Z**1.5) * sym.exp(-Z*r)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you looking to integrate f(r) over r ?   or are you looking for some change of coordinates from elliptic to carthesian? i'm not sure..

Comment: More people will understand you here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import integrate

r = sym.Symbol('r')
Z = sym.Symbol('Z', constant = True) 
integrate('(1/(pi)) * (Z**1.5) * exp(-Z*r)', r, Z)
```

Output:

[image]